# Use value of a document as query while searching for another document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have 2 collections in my mongo database. The first one stores search queries to look up documents in the 2nd table. A certain set of users can modify these search queries, while another set of users is allowed to search the 2nd collection.

Example
**document in collection 1**

```
{
    "sid":"1",
    "search":{"id":{"$in":["a", "b", "c"]}}
},
{   
    "sid": "2",
    "search":{"field":{"$in":["p", "q", "r"]}}
}
```

**document in collection2**

```
{
     "id":"a",
     "field": "s"
},
{
     "id":"b",
     "field": "r"
},
{
     "id":"f",
     "field": "p"
},
{   
    "id" : "x",
    "field" : "a"   
}
```

I need to run a single aggregate query where I can input "sid" as "1" or as "2", and if "sid" is set to "1", the documents returned should be as follows

```
{
     "id":"a"
     "field": "s",
},
{
     "id":"b"
     "field": "r",
}
```

If the "sid" is set to 2 in the aggregate query the result should be

```
{
     "id":"b"
     "field": "r",
},
{
     "id":"f"
     "field": "p",
}
```

Please understand this is a minimized problem, and what I need is how to convert a value in the field of a document in one collection to be used as a query while searching for documents in another collection through a single aggregate query.

I understand that this might be a "preposterous" problem to solve, but it definitely has applications in my end project.

So far I have tried the following aggregate query

```
db.search.aggregate([
     {
          "$lookup": {
               "from": "docs",
               "let": {
                    "search": "$search"
               },
               "pipeline": [
                    {
                         "$match": {
                              "$expr": {
                                   "$or": "$$search"
                              }
                         }
                    }
               ],
               "as": "docs"
          }
     },
     {
          "$match": {
               "sid": "1"
          }
     }
])
```

But I end up getting

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("64c2a3707da736fbb9051b9a"),
    "sid" : "1",
    "search" : {
        "id" : {
            "$in" : [
                "a",
                "b",
                "c"
            ]
        }
    },
    "docs" : [
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("64c2a3b17da736fbb9051b9c"),
            "id" : "a",
            "field" : "s"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("64c2a3b17da736fbb9051b9d"),
            "id" : "b",
            "field" : "r"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("64c2a3b17da736fbb9051b9e"),
            "id" : "f",
            "field" : "p"
        },
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("64c2a5257da736fbb9051b9f"),
            "id" : "x",
            "field" : "a"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here the docs with id "x" and id "f" are not expected

Comment: Is there other matching logic besides `$in` that can be specified in the docs in the first collection? If not then I think what you want is easily achievable. If so, then this becomes more difficult

Comment: The $in is just an example. Ideally any query which works with find is game for the search filed.

Comment: My impression is that this is quite difficult to do. I don't think there is "direct" support for what you want (embedding a query inside of a document and then using that as an argument dynamically in a operation). I'd further speculate that, even though it may be possible to achieve in a single aggregate query (with significant effort), it would probably be (much) more performant to actually pull the data back to the client and issue a second query. Watching to see if someone more clever has other thoughts though